# Cancel ManipulationStarting event to prevent drag&drop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, windows-runtime, routed-events

There are several events which deal with manipulation (and thus drag&drop):

- ManipulationStarting
- ManipulationStarted
- ManipulationDelta
- ManipulationInertiaStarting
- ManipulationCompleted

In the ManipulationStarting event, the event args (type [ManipulationStartingRoutedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.manipulationstartingroutedeventargs)) allow me to set the Mode attribute to ManipulationModes.None -- is it correct that this means that no manipulation is allowed and thus no drag&drop?

I'm asking because I've come across a strange behaviour when I was playing with the official [XAML user input events sample application](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-3dff271b), especially with scenario 4 (drag&drop).

Just set the Mode to ManipulationModes.None in the ManipulationStarting event of Scenario4.xaml.cs:

```
void ManipulateMe_ManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    forceManipulationsToEnd = false;
    e.Mode = ManipulationModes.None;   // <-- this is new
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Nevertheless, with every third drag attempt I can drag the rectangle around. I've recorded a video to demonstrate this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psytuTailHg.

This problem does not only occur with this sample but also in my own application.

#### Questions:

- Why is there such a strange behavior?
- What's the best way to cancel the drag&drop event (for instance if some conditions are not met)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a gridview for example you can implement the DragItemStarting event, and set `e.Cancel = true;` to prevent this behaviour - does that not meet your needs?